# Stuck on setting up git-tf for OSX Mountain Lion xCode - TFS integration

Tags: xcode, osx-mountain-lion, path-variables, git-tf

I have been trying to follow the instructions (Git-TF_GettingStarted.html) to set up git - tf integration from xcode to TFS 2010

I think my problem is setting up the path variables correctly.

I am in terminal, and created a .profile file via "open .profile"

I entered the following two lines:

```
export PATH=”/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core/”:$PATH 
export PATH=”/Users/ssmith/Git-Tf/”:$PATH
```

saved, started terminal, but terminal doesn't recognize my commands:

```
Stevens-MacBook-Pro:~ ssmith$ git tf
-bash: git: command not found
```

Do you have any idea what i am missing?

Comment: Are those really ” characters and not " (ASCII 0x22)?  What does your `$PATH` look like now?  Is `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin` in it?

Comment: No, thats the entire contents of the file.

Comment: Can you *add* `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin`?

Comment: @EdwardThomson Actually the quotes were incorrect - i fixed them and now the path variables work. Then I ran into a problem with java - to fix i went to the root folder, typed "java", and it installed itself. and finally now git-tf runs (doesnt work quite yet due to an authentication issue). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

From that error message, I am guessing that git isn't installed, or at least not installed properly. See http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git#Installing-on-Mac on how to get git setup on a Mac.

Comment: that is a good guess but somehow the wrong quote character made it into my path file (see my comment above). Thanks for trying to help!